# should my angular js web application have only one module?

Tags: angularjs

I have read a lot about angular directives and controllers and could gather that all variables and scope high amount of processing at the client level, can this be reduced by using multiple modules in your application and is it recommended to have more than one modules in your web app? Pls describe a design scenario where having more than one app is beneficial for the web app.

Well after the edit and  reading responses I would like to know if it is advisable to have more than one modules in your app because i have used multiple modules only when i had to inject a dependency like angular-ui or angular-router... but what ever features angular ui offers is actually directives. So if there is a re-usable generic code should it be put in separate module? so that it becomes a kind of plug in code for various other web apps? Is it the best practice?

Comment: Whenever they're doing very different, non-overlapping jobs.

Comment: If you should only have one module in the app, you wouldn't be able to add modules. So yes, it is perfectly acceptable to have multiple modules in the app. Also you can only ever have one app per web page

Comment: @Liam: one ng-app per web page. But you can bootstrap additional ones.

Comment: You can have multiple modules per app and multiple apps per website (you have to bootstrap them manually like JB Nizet said though). Although, this is irrelevant to the amount of "processing". Angular is wicked fast and can handle scopes with thousands of properties. Unless you have a very unique scenario, I wouldn't worry about performance. It is recommended to have multiple modules purely as a code design practice. Modularity and separation of concerns are always a good thing.

Comment: "Pls [sic] describe a design scenario where having more than one app is beneficial for the web app." That's a bit broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing about the organization of code is not so simple. It depend in his majority of how big or scalable is your application. I mean that is not a **obligatory** using several modules but the tendency is for this way because the AngularJS today applications are more powerful.

The most popular templates in the web had a single modules and they are: [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) and [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for Yeoman.

The project that have several modules normally are big project where it is necesary a certainly organization and the necessity of keep simple the controllers and views. For example imagine that you have to do a email application. A sample structure should be:

```
EmailApp
   DashBoard
   Inbox
     Tray
   Compose
     Editor
   Span
   Common
```

Resuming there 4 mainly predefined structures for organize the code:

1. Monolithic files(all the controllers in controllers.js, services in services.js, etc)
2. Organizate by type(a folder for each controller)

Comment: so say if my Inbox and Compose functionality have different views ,controllers and services i.e. disjoint. so either i can make separate controllers in same module  or i can throw them in separate modules with different controllers so is making separate modules good practice?

Comment: Sorry, i check out right now and my answers was more extensive and SO cutted.

Comment: The two structured that left was Organize by Functionality(is the above) and organize by funcionality and by type. The thing is a better option for extensive app is have separate modules by functionalities, and then inside this separates controllers, views, filters, services, etc. Maybe you want to put it all in separate folders,maybe no is your choice. And there must be a shared or common module that has the what is common for all modules, like data retrieval service, directives, filters, evenly controllers like navControllers(the controller for the navegation).